# Google Places Api returns only single result

Tags: android, google-places-api

Google Places API renders only single result if I use it in an AutoCompleteTextView. This issue occurs from the second request., i.e., for the first time the list is loaded properly with 5 results. 
Used [ [PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter][1]](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java) as an adapter.

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, mGoogleApiClient, null,
            null);
AutoCompleteTextView eventLocation.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

[image: Attaching a screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Please check edit. Further I have used an OnItemClickListener to get the specific place with id from the autoComplete drop-down.